# Spring MVC Interceptor : Do some logic in postHandle based on value in preHandle

Tags: spring, interceptor

I want to do some logic in **postHandle** in my custom Interceptors which are extending **HandlerInterceptorAdapter** if **preHandle** returns with "true"

how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification of the spring interceptor says:

> The preHandle(..) method returns a boolean value. You can use this method to break or continue the processing of the execution chain. When this method returns true, the handler execution chain will continue; when it returns false, the DispatcherServlet assumes the interceptor itself has taken care of requests (and, for example, rendered an appropriate view) and does not continue executing the other interceptors and the actual handler in the execution chain. [[1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)]

Therefore, if you return `false` from `preHandle()`, the handler will not be executed and consequently the `postHandle()` will not fire as well. In other words, no explicit check of the return value of `preHandle()` is required.